# SyncRoot property in Powershell

Tags: powershell, syncroot

This question is regarding the function forward_dns from the following blog: 
http://powershellmasters.blogspot.com/2009/04/nslookup-and-powershell.html

So say I have a piece of code in powershell that looks like this:

```
$cmd = "nslookup google.com " + $NameserverIPAddress;
$result = Invoke-Expression ($cmd);
```

This snippet uses the nslookup DOS command to do a DNS lookup. Since it's a DOS command, the object returned by Invoke-Expression is basically an array of strings, one for each line of output.

In the example function, in order to retrieve line 4 of the output, the original author uses the following syntax:

```
$result.SyncRoot[3];
```

I found that this also works just fine:

```
$result[3];
```

What is the purpose of SyncRoot in this context?

Answer (score 1):

There is no purpose in this example.
`SyncRoot` property is a way to treat in a safe manner ( generally with a lock in .net) arrays handled by more that one thread. see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Collections-Data-Structure/ArraySyncRootPropertysynchronizeaccesstoanarray.htm) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.array.syncroot.aspx)

Comment: great, thanks! That's kind of what I thought. A bit useless in powershell, since as far as I'm aware, Powershell doesn't support threads... There's a way better way to do what this guy was trying to do anyway.